# Pdf 2 Tiff Convertion For Pika Faxing

Tags: java, image, tiff, fax

I am working on converting a pdf file to tiff images for faxing in java.Pika applications are responsible to process and send created tiff file.Everything is fine,tiff file is created with the tags.But Pika is not sending tiff file.It gives an error about unsupported file format.Pika error message is below

> -- (PK_STATUS PKH_ERROR_FAX_UNSUPPORTED_FILE_FORMAT)

What is the problem,what i am missing,someone can help ? Tiff tag data

```
SubFileType (1 Long): Page
ImageWidth (1 Long): 1728
ImageLength (1 Long): 2297
BitsPerSample (1 Short): 1
Compression (1 Short): Group 4 Fax (aka CCITT FAX4)
Photometric (1 Short): MinIsWhite
FillOrder (1 Short): Lsb2Msb
StripOffsets (288 Long): 2625, 2629, 2633, 2637, 2641, 2645, 2649,...
SamplesPerPixel (1 Short): 1
RowsPerStrip (1 Long): 8
StripByteCounts (288 Long): 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,...
XResolution (1 Rational): 204
YResolution (1 Rational): 196
Group4Options (1 Long): 0
ResolutionUnit (1 Short): Inch
PageNumber (2 Short): 0, 1
Software (19 ASCII): DDoc2TiffConverter 
DateTime (20 ASCII): 2013:09:08 23:35:17 
BadFaxLines (1 Long): 0
CleanFaxData (1 Short): 0
ConsecutiveBadFaxLines (1 Long): 0
```

Comment: Fax transmissions are usually Group 3 1D or 2D; maybe it can't handle you sending it G4 data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem.It was related with the strip count of the tiff image.Converted from multi-strip to single strip and then it was successful to send tiff via fax.To be informative i will share how tiff was converted from multi to single strip.

```
TIFFEncodeParam param = new TIFFEncodeParam();
param.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_GROUP4);
param.setReverseFillOrder(true);

param.setLittleEndian(true);
param.setWriteTiled(false);
param.setTileSize(-1, images[0].getHeight());
```

param.setTileSize(-1, images[0].getHeight()); This part sets to the single strip.